# How to update a table column where column name is dynamic

Tags: c#, sql-server, edit

I have a table with five fields. I want to update any of them by clicking a field. But i do not know which field will be edited that means column_name is not predefined.My code is here

```
 public void Edit(int Id, string field, string oldValue, string newValue, object customer)
{ 

    BanglaFireExt.DAL.ExtDotNetEntities db = new BanglaFireExt.DAL.ExtDotNetEntities();

    string message = "<b>Property:</b> {0}<br /><b>Field:</b> {1}<br /><b>Old Value:</b> {2}<br /><b>New Value:</b> {3}";
    var obj = db.Employees.Single(x=>x.Id==Id);
    **obj.field=newValue;**//here field is a string, but there is a column in table named **field value**
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

How can i convert string to table column type. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to set a property with the name passed as the field parameter? You can use Reflection.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperty(field).SetValue(obj, newValue);
```